# how to write and read byte array to shared preference

Tags: java, android

i like to save microphone data to shared preference as a byte[] . i found this below method in stack but its not working  distorted sound like minions

saving to shared pref

```
                int  index = 0;
            while(index != 1000) {
                index++;

                //reading data from MIC into buffer
                minBufSize = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                // Store Buffer to shared pref
                String saveThis = Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.DEFAULT);


                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("data_" + index, saveThis);
                editor.apply();

                // mark realtime database
                System.out.println("MinBufferSize: " + minBufSize);


            }
```

reading back

```
                int  index = 0;
            while(index != 1000) {
                index++;

                // get dat from firebase Storage
                String dataName = "data_"+ index;

                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
                String data = prefs.getString(dataName , null);//"No name defined" is the default value.
                bufferPlay = Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT);

                speaker.write(bufferPlay, 0, 1280);
                // set buffer
                Log.d("T", String.valueOf(index));


            }
```

Comment: You are converting the audio bytes in your byte array to a string and even with a char encoding. That is impossible. Not the way to go. You can never get the original bytes back. Please remove all your code as its irrelevant. Then come back with a byte array and ask how to save a byte array to shared preferences.

Comment: @blackapps how can i save buffer correctly and retrieve

Comment: Encode the bytes in your byte array base64. Then you will get a nice string that you can save in shared preferences.

Comment: @blackapps same result distorted sound i am updating my question

Comment: "i tried this Encode the bytes in your byte array base64" You show the code where you decode the bytes, but not where you encode them.

Comment: Yes, please show with encoding.

Comment: @blackapps sorry for the delay family troubles . i updated the code please check

Comment: You are not saving string `saveThis` to shared preverences. And `dataName` is not `au_ + index`.

Comment: @blackapps that was a mistake final code i updated still distorted

Comment: `minBufSize = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);` Why are you calling that variable minBufSize? As read() returns the number of bytes read. It could be less than the buffer size. In the following statement you encode the whole buffer but that is no good if the buffer is not filled. `int nread = recorder.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);String saveThis = Base64.encodeToString(buffer, 0, nread,  Base64.DEFAULT);`